# Classic ASP Page that uses JavaScript crashing on new ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, iis, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I have a asp classic page but the language is set on javascript. like this

`<%@ Language=JavaScript %>`

if I try to create a http request like this

```
   var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0");
```

or

```
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

the page just crashes with a generic error saying like an internal server error occurred. Does anyone know how I can investigate and fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That code is not meant to execute on the server. It's meant to execute client-side. The server does not have an XHR component installed on it.

Comment: This part ` var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0");` actually works on an old server, but it's not working on the new server.

Comment: @omega Because the new server doesn't have that ActiveX control installed on it.

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: You can read that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507432(v=vs.85).aspx). But, really you should not be still be doing things the way they were done 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to enable detailed error pages in IIS to get rid of generic error pages.

I'd bet it was a `ActiveX component can't create object` error but see [How To Configure IIS7 To Show ASP Errors?](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1782) it's a hepful guide with screenshots.

MSXML 4.0 is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Using `MSXML 6.0` instead is recommended. It's compatible with `4.0`, so replacing `4.0` with `6.0` is sufficient.

See [MSXML Roadmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152146(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

So, use `var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");` or if you too picky, instantiate the object like below for the sake of backward compatibility.

```
var xmlhttp;
try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0");
}
catch(e) {
    try
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
    } 
    catch(e) 
    {
        throw "object can't created";
    }
}
```